# Google Places API: Understanding the parsing of the Places Autocomplete response

Tags: javascript, for-loop, google-places-api

I'm trying to finish a project that was left to me by my classmate, however because of my lack of experience in the subject I tend to be stuck in a certain block of code in which I think, if I could understand I can finish the project without anymore problem. I know you might say, why not ask him instead, I tried but I got no answer and my clock is ticking.

Here is the part/block of code that I don't understand, if you could explain it to me I would be very grateful.

He declares a variable

```
 var component_form = {
    'street_number': 'short_name',
    'route': 'long_name',
    'locality': 'long_name',
    'administrative_area_level_1': 'short_name',
    'country': 'long_name',
    'postal_code': 'short_name'
  };
```

I think the variable is for this function

```
function fillInAddress() {
    var place = autocomplete.getPlace();

    for (var component in component_form) {
      document.getElementById(component).value = "";
      document.getElementById(component).disabled = false;
    }

    for (var j = 0; j < place.address_components.length; j++) {
      var att = place.address_components[j].types[0];
      if (component_form[att]) {
        var val = place.address_components[j][component_form[att]];
        document.getElementById(att).value = val;
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: what do you not understand? Where are you stuck?

Comment: sir the declared variable component_form, and how the second for loop works.

Comment: what the current webpage does is  a user inputs an address and it fills in the labels

Comment: use console.log() for printing variables to the console, like console.log(place), console.log(att) and console.log(val), you will see what is inside them and I sure if you see a place object(and its data) you will understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check the [Place Details](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/details#PlaceDetailsRequests) response from the Google Places API. 
Below is just a snippet i copied from that link above. 
If you look at your second `for` loop and compare it with what you are doing with the looping and the Place Details response object.

the attributes such as `street_number` from the response are assigned to the same variables in your `component_form`

```
"html_attributions" : [],
   "result" : {
      "address_components" : [
         {
            "long_name" : "48",
            "short_name" : "48",
            "types" : [ "street_number" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Pirrama Road",
            "short_name" : "Pirrama Road",
            "types" : [ "route" ]
         },
         {
            "long_name" : "Pyrmont",
            "short_name" : "Pyrmont",
            "types" : [ "locality", "political" ]
         },
```

### EDIT

When you further mine the Place API. Here is what the Autocomplete response contains

`types` contains an array of types that apply to this place. For example: [ "political", "locality" ] or [ "establishment", "geocode" ].

In your case, you are fetching the value at the `0th index` in the `types` array.

```
  var att = place.address_components[j].types[0];
```

which would give you `street_number`.Your code verifies if it exists in your `component_form`. If it does, assigns the value `short_name` from the autocomplete response object.

So, i am assuming you are requesting for the parameters for autocomplete with the query as such `types=street_number` in the URL. For the next you would have `types=route` (since you get always the 0th index only)

Hope this helps.